# Parallelize downloads across hostnames - Magento

Tags: php, cdn, magento-1.8

I'd like to know how I can implement "Parallelize downloads across hostnames" on Magento?

I can setup different CDN resources but how do I serve files from media across different CDN resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallelized downloads (also known as domain sharding) was a well known practice with HTTP/1.1. It was a concept that worked with some [limitations](https://gtmetrix.com/parallelize-downloads-across-hostnames-common-problems.html). With the rise of [HTTP/2](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/keycdn-http2-support/), multiplexing was introduced.

> **Multiplexing**: Allowing multiple requests and responses to be sent at the same time.

This means that many assets can be delivered from the same domain in parallel and makes domain sharding obsolete. 
If your CDN supports HTTP/2, there's no need anymore for parallelized downloads. A number of CDNs already [support HTTP/2](http://cdncomparison.com/). Your Magento setup will stay the same, no changes required for HTTP/2.